# SQL Inner Join only one row based on filtered records

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following tables

**user**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jack |
| 3 | George |

**essay**

| id | date_submitted | user_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2020-05-01 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2020-04-10 | 3 | 2 |

**project_phase**

| id | project_id | date | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | early |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-05-31 | mid |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-11-30 | late |
| 4 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | early |
| 5 | 2 | 2020-03-31 | mid |
| 6 | 2 | 2020-04-30 | late |

1 User submits only 1 essay in one project
and I want to have a combined table which shows me the user and the phase at which the essay was submitted.

I'm trying to get the record with the MAX date from project_phase that is below the date_submitted

**So using the above data I want to get**

| user | date_submitted | phase |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2020-12-10 | late |
| Jack | 2020-05-01 | late |
| George | 2020-04-10 | mid |

so far I combined the tables with INNER JOIN but the following query returns duplicate records. I also tried ROW_NUMBER() and MAX() but I didn't structure it correctly to get the answer I'm looking for

```
SELECT
    U.name,
    E.date_submitted,
    P.phase
FROM
    essay E
INNER JOIN user U ON U.id = E.user_id
INNER JOIN project_phase P ON P.project_id = E.project_id and E.date <= P.date_submitted
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT U.name, E.date_submitted,
       (SELECT P.phase
        FROM project_phase P
        WHERE P.project_id = E.project_id AND
              P.date <= E.date_submitted 
        ORDER BY p.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as phase
FROM essay E JOIN
     user U
     ON U.id = E.user_id;
```

Comment: Seem ok except : change line WHERE  into   :  WHERE P.project_id = E.project_id AND

Comment: That was a quick response! Just run some checks in about 100K rows and everything looks good. Thank you!!